# Turn an XML string into an Object in Actionscript

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, xml-deserialization

I am pretty new to AS, and I am assuming there is a way to do this and I am just not figuring it out.  Basically, I am trying to use a service that returns xml and return an Object regardless of the structure of the xml.  In .Net I use the **XmlSerializer.Deserialize** class... is there equivalent in AS?

I was able to find **SimpleXMLDecoder** but I can't seem to get it to work - it also looks like it might only work with nodes?  Either way, the examples out there are sparse and hard to follow, I just want to know how to take xml like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<Company>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Stan</Name>
    <Size>10</Size>
</Company>;
```

And simply turn it into an **Object** - is this possible without writing my own parser?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`HTTPService`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html)

There's a good example here...

- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/07/27/loading-xml-at-run-time-using-the-mxhttpservice-tag/
- and here http://colourgray.wordpress.com/2008/08/08/flex-processing-xml-response-from-httpservice/

Basically it will serialize the result into an object from XML when you retrieve it.

Comment: Hello, the HTTPService works fine but needs the Flex SDK that is not available if you use only the Flash ide.

Comment: It's available, you can just get the SDK, since it's free. However, if you just have an xml string and don't need the other features of HTTPService, just do `var x:XML = XML(string);`

Comment: wow... that is super easy, I should have asked this question earlier!

Answer (score 5):

ActionScript has its own `XML` parser then you don't need to write yours.

#### XML from a String

If you have a `String` to convert, you can just convert it as `XML` inline with few lines of code like this:

```
import flash.xml.*;

var xml : XML = XML( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Company><Id>2</Id><Name>Stan</Name><Size>10</Size></Company>' );

trace( 'Id:' + xml.Id ); // Should trace "2"
trace( 'Name:' + xml.Name ); // Should trace "Stan"
```

#### XML from an external file

Otherwise you can just load it in runtime in this way:

```
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.xml.*;

var xmlLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, doStuffWithLoadedXML );

function doStuffWithLoadedXML( e : Event ) : void 
{                             
    var xml : XML = new XML( e.target.data );
    trace( 'Id:' + xml.Id ); // Should trace "2"
    trace( 'Name:' + xml.Name ); // Should trace "Stan"
}

xmlLoader.load( new URLRequest( 'yourfile.xml' ) );
```

#### Edited with links

Some nice links to start working:

**The Basic**
http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=242

**Some nice E4X tips and how-to**
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4

Hope this helps. Ciao!

Comment: I wish I could mark two answers, this is correct too - I was just using services, so that worked out easier.  Thank you!

Comment: It's ok man. That's the rule of the game and @Slomojo comes first ;-) Good luck!