# How to convert XML to actionscript object

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

I have a xml file and actionscript classes for same xml file.

eg: xml file

```
 <element name="Student">
    <element name="FirstName">
        <value>Sachin</value>
    </element>
</element>
```

as3  classes:

Student.as

```
package generated {     
     public class Student{    

       public var firstName:FirstName = new FirstName();    
    }    
}

FirstName.as
package generated { 
     public class FirstName{
        public var value:String;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to convert above xml into actionscript object.

Is there any tool?

Please, help...... Thanks...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your choices are:

- Parse and deserialize yourself, mapping your XML to your own objects.
- Use a serializer / deserializer from a library.
- Cast as objects, use a HTTPService.

Using service methods, Flex can handle XML as native objects; however, this would not map to classes you've typed.  You might be able to follow patterns of Flex remoting services to correctly map to class definitions without duct typing.

Not quite what you're after, but turning XML to an object has been asked here: [Turn an XML string into an Object in Actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929193/turn-an-xml-string-into-an-object-in-actionscript)

Answer (score 0):

```
public var xmlFileName:String;
    private var urlL:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    private var urlR:URLRequest;
    public var xml:XML = new XML();
    public var target_id:String= new String();

    public function loadXML(xmlS:String):void
    {
        xmlFileName = xmlS;
        urlR =  new URLRequest(xmlFileName);            
      //  urlL.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressAction);
        urlL.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedAction);
       // urlL.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorAction);
        urlL.load(urlR);            
    }
    public function onLoadedAction(e:Event):void
    {
        xml = XML(e.target.data);
        target_id = xml.element.value[0];
        dispatchEvent ( new Event ( Event.COMPLETE ) )
        //trace(xml);
    }
```

//and in your FirstName class

```
private function init():void
{
    xmlData = new loadXML("list.xml");
    // listen for loading completed
    xmlData.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE, handleXMLLoaded );
}

private function handleXMLLoaded (e:Event):void
{
   var xmlF:XML = xmlData.xml
   var value:String = xmlData.target_id;
   //trace(xmlF); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. for quick reply. But, at the end I want xml value through actionscript classes. for eg: I want "Sachin" value through var value:String = firstName.value;

Comment: I did some changes. chk with that.